# DOM create xml from php- htmlspecialchars() Troubles with adding greater than to xml &gt;

Tags: php, xml, htmlspecialchars

I am creating xml file from php and I am not able to add to  bold line $category->nodeValue='Foot>Ordinary foot' symbol greater than. If I view file there is >
I have tried htmlspecialchars and nodeTextValue but nothing woks correctly.
Thanks a lot for help. I have UTF-8  coding
V

```
    $dom = new DomDocument();
$dom->encoding = "UTF-8";
$dom->formatOutput = true;

$root = $dom->createElement('itemlist');
$dom->appendChild($root);

$dataPackItem = $dom->createElement('item');
$root->appendChild($dataPackItem);

$product_category = $dom->createElement('product_category');
$dataPackItem->appendChild($product_category);  

$category = $dom->createElement('category');
$category->setAttribute('id', '63');    
**$category->nodeValue='Foot>Ordinary foot';**

$product_category->appendChild($category);      


echo '<xmp>'. $dom->saveXML() .'</xmp>';
$dom->save('images/export_sz_opencart.xml') or die('XML Create Error');
```

Comment: Supplied code works as-is. https://3v4l.org/DpVGX Whatever you're using to view the result is likely converting the entity for display.

Comment: Set `textContent`, not `nodeValue`. `nodeValue` has a broken escaping.

Comment: both textContent and replay from Sammitch exporting <category id="63">Foot&gt;Ordinary foot</category> but I need export <category id="63">Foot>Ordinary foot</category>

Comment: I need nodeValue or text content Foot>Ordinary foot